# Apply column vector to each row of each matrix in array in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

If I have the array

```
> (arr = array(c(1,1,2,2), c(2,2,2)))

, , 1

     [,1] [,2]

[1,]    1    2

[2,]    1    2

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]

[1,]    1    2

[2,]    1    2
```

then how could I apply a column vector, say c(3,3), to each row of each matrix and sum these up?  So essentially, I need to do 4 * c(1,2) %*% c(3,3).  Could an apply function be used here?

Comment: Do you need to have an array or can you use a list as well?

Comment: Sure, I could use a list as well.

Comment: @nongkrong Hmm, I do not think this always works.

Comment: @nongkrong Well I could, and it would produce a 2x1 vector, and then I could sum the elements of the resulting vector to obtain what I want.  But I would get two 2x1 vectors, and I need to sum the components of all the vectors to get my answer.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Would `a1 <- apply(arr, c(1,3), sum);sum(mapply('%*%', arr, a1))` this work

Comment: I just tried sum(apply(arr, c(1,3), function(x) x %*% c(3,3,3))), which seems to work and yours gives a different answer?

Comment: I got 36 as the answer which I got from your formula in the comments i.e. `c(1,2) %*% c(3,3) + c(1,2) %*% c(3,3) + c(1,2) %*% c(3,3) + c(1,2) %*% c(3,3)#  [,1]
[1,]   36`

Comment: @akrun Ah okay, so I created a new array to check and we have differing results, one of which should be the correct method.  I will do an example by hand to figure out which ;)

Comment: Oh okay.  May be you are right.  I didn't test it with other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the help!  I believe the correct method is

```
sum(apply(arr, c(1,3), function(x) x %*% c(1,2,3)))
```

which here we are dotting the vector [1,2,3] to each row of each matrix in our array called arr and summing them up.  Note that here I changed the array to be

```
arr = array(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12), c(2,3,2))

arr

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]

[1,]    1    3    5

[2,]    2    4    6

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]

[1,]    7    9   11

[2,]    8   10   12
```

and now the vector we are dotting the rows with is c(1,2,3) instead of c(3,3) in the original post.

Comment: Are you sure it works?  I get error `Error in x %*% c(1, 2, 3) : non-conformable arguments` using your example

Comment: I was using the new array to test our two methods.  I should specify it above, I will fix it now.

Comment: what will be your modification for the original `arr`

Comment: @akrun You would just need to change the vector c(1,2,3) to whatever you wish to dot it with.  The original arr had 2x2 matrices in it, so you would need a 2x1 vector instead of the 3x1 vector I used above.

Comment: Okay.  In that case, you may also need to show that to avoid any confusiong for somebody reading your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

This should give you the answer:

```
l <- list(matrix(c(1,1,2,2), ncol = 2),
      matrix(c(1,1,2,2), ncol = 2))
l
#[[1]]
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    1    2
# 
# [[2]]
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    1    2


ivector <- c(3, 3) # a vector that is multiplied with the rows of each listelement
# apply over all listelements
res <- lapply(l, function(x, ivector){

    #apply to all rows of the matrizes
    apply(x, 1, function(rowel, ivector){
       return(sum(rowel %*% ivector))
    }, ivector = ivector)

}, ivector = ivector)

res
#[[1]]
#[1] 9 9
#
#[[2]] 
#[1] 9 9

# And finally sum up the results:
sum(Reduce("+", res))
#[1] 36
```

Does that help?

Comment: Not exactly.  I want, c(1,2) %*% c(3,3) + c(1,2) %*% c(3,3) + c(1,2) %*% c(3,3) + c(1,2) %*% c(3,3), where the first two additions are from the first matrix and the last two are the second matrix.  I will try to modify your lapply function here.

Comment: I think I got it now, is that better?

Comment: In R, that is how you create a vector?  I am sorry but I am not sure how else to explain it.  I have a matrix, but I just want to apply a vector to each row, and sum up the results.

Comment: @nongkrong What I mean by "apply" here is to dot the rows of each matrix with a specified column vector.  Sorry for the poor wording.

Comment: It seems to work if you then sum up those entries, i.e. 9 + 9 + 9 + 9.  I have not tried it for a different example though like I did with my method.